# How can I hide YouTube comments from my Google+ stream?

Tags: youtube, google-plus

Lately my Google+ stream seems to consist almost entirely of comments people posted on YouTube videos.

I have absolutely no interest in seeing these. How can I hide/filter these posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean your own videos or other people's Youtube videos.  Here's what I've found.

Go to https://plus.google.com/settings then scroll down to "**Receive notifications**" click on "**Posts**" and then unselect the last option "**Shares or comments on your content across the web (for example, your YouTube videos or your blog)**"

Also you may want to make sure when you comment on a Youtube video that the "**Also share on Google+**" option is off.  Follow up comment are most likely considered responses and will show up on the stream (I'm not sure about that though).